# MIPS BNE Machine Code Conversion

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code, mars-simulator

I am attempting to convert about 25 lines of a MIPS program from machine code into instructions.

When I convert the machine code of `0x1620fff9`, it yields the following:
        `000101 10001 00000 1111 1111 1111 1001`

I understand this is I-format, and the instruction is `BNE` with a target register of `$17` and a source of `$0`, however the immediate/address is what I am confused about.

As `1111 1111 1111 1001` is a signed number, its two's complement yields a result of `-7`. I just dont know what to do with that result. The MARS simulator needs a label for where it should branch to, but I am unclear as to what to do. The program I am converting only has a main function and a print function.

Thanks

Comment: Add a label at the proper instruction, or use the symbol for the current address which is normally `.`, `$` or `*` (depending on assembler). You could write something like `bne $s0, $t0, .-7` (adjust the offset as necessary).

Comment: The offset in the branch instruction is a *word* offset, so you need to multiply by 4 to get a byte offset, giving `bne $s0, $t0, . - 28`

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Whenever MARS sees the bne command, it says that it is expecting 'bne $t1, $t2, label', so both solutions above do not seem to work for mars. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that MARS and QTSpim handle those instructions differently:

- MARS always jumps from the instruction after the branch instruction which is exactly what a pipelined machine is supposed to do;
- QtSPIM jumps from the branch instruction, which is easier to understand.
- Under MARS, bne instruction is 0x1620fff8, while under QtSPIM, it is 0x1620fff9.

Our professor made concessions for the differing results, but I thought that this may be useful to someone in the future.

Comment: Some people consider exposing pipeline details in the ISA (e.g. the branch-delay slot, or basically everything about IA-64) to be a big design mistake.  It's an inconvenience that gives no benefit on future implementations of the architecture that do out-of-order execution, for example.  Linus Torvalds has posted about stuff like this on the http://realworldtech.com/ forums (but they're not searchable, xD).